why getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deepchecks.tabular' even thouh deepchecks is installed?
While trying to install the deepchecks framework for testing my ML project using
pip install deepchecks --upgrade I got following error.

meson setup C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dhiqjs\scipy_0749651b5b2c448299baaf506e009bba C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-
install-dhiqjs\scipy_0749651b5b2c448299baaf506e009bba.mesonpy-zwzbqwrf -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dhiqjs\scipy_0749651b5b2c448299baaf506e009bba.mesonpy-zwzbqwrf\meson-python-native-file.ini
The Meson build system
Version: 1.4.1
Source dir: C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dhiqjs\scipy_0749651b5b2c448299baaf506e009bba
Build dir: C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dhiqjs\scipy_0749651b5b2c448299baaf506e009bba.mesonpy-zwzbqwrf
Build type: native build
Project name: SciPy
Project version: 1.9.3
Activating VS 17.10.3
C compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.40.33811 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.40.33811 for x64")
C linker for the host machine: link link 14.40.33811.0
C++ compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.40.33811 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.40.33811 for x64")
C++ linker for the host machine: link link 14.40.33811.0
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO (cached)
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: NO
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-conversion: NO
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-misleading-indentation: NO
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types: NO
Library m found: NO
..\meson.build:57:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['ifort'], ['gfortran'], ['flang'], ['pgfortran'], ['g95']]
The following exception(s) were encountered:
Running ifort --version gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
Running ifort -V gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
Running gfortran --version gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
Running gfortran -V gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
Running flang --version gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
Running flang -V gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
Running pgfortran --version gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
Running pgfortran -V gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
Running g95 --version gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
Running g95 -V gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
A full log can be found at C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dhiqjs\scipy_0749651b5b2c448299baaf506e009bba.mesonpy-zwzbqwrf\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
[end of output]


note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
However, when I tried installing deepchecks using conda
conda install -c conda-forge deepchecks
it worked like a charm.
Now, even though deepchecks is installed, certain submodules are not getting imported.
from deepchecks.suites import single_dataset_integrity works without any complain. However,
from deepchecks.tabular.suites import data_integrity throws error like
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deepchecks.tabular'
